# Css to position a element at specific position

Tags: css

I'd want to position a `div` component at specific location, for example,

```
<div class "products"><div class="star"></div></div>
```

*star* is to display a product rated star
and I set it in css as

```
.star
{left:10px;}
```

I'd want to change `10px` when the user resizes the screen. It has to be changed too in relation to the screen size of product. How can I do that?

Comment: Use relative units https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: But then how can I get the top and left values of the star when the program is running?  want to display left=x, top=y even when I resize the window.

Comment: You can use percentage of the parent container (`x%`) or percentage of the screen (`xvh`) for. for advanced  usage of coordinates use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

`realtive;` => Position an element based on its current position without changing layout.

`absolute` => Position an element based on its parent

```css
.parent{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
position: relative;
}
.child{
background-color: blue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Voilà</h2>
<div class="parent">
<p class="child">
uK
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the example below

Use % for the left it will change depend on the width of the container

```css
.products {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="star">****</div>
</div>
```